# Serialize objects to XML, only use reference ID

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have an object defined which contains components. Each component can contain other components as subcomponents. Something like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class Thing
{
    private String name;
    private List<MyComponent> components;
    //...
}

[Serializable]
public class MyComponent
{
    private String name;
    private List<MyComponent> subcomponents;
    private String componentID;
    //...
}
```

Serialization is very simple right now:

```
 Thing t;
 //...lots of stuff happens...
 XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(t.GetType());
 x.Serialize(fstream, t);
```

When I serialize an object of type `Thing` to XML, I get something that looks like this:

```
<Thing>
  <ID>TH_001<ID>
  <Name>My Test Thing</Name>
  <Components>
     <MyComponent>
        <ComponentID>CMP_001</ComponentID>
            <Name>Foo</Name>
        </MyComponent>        
        <MyComponent>
            <ComponentID>CMP_002</ComponentID>
            <Name>Bar</Name>
            <Subcomponents>
                <MyComponent>
                    <ComponentID>CMP_001</ComponentID>
                     <Name>Foo</Name>
                <MyComponent>
            </Subcomponents>
        </MyComponent>
        <MyComponent>
            <ComponentID>CMP_003</ComponentID>
            <Name>Blergle</Name>
        </MyComponent>   
        <MyComponent>
           <ID>CMP_004</ID>
           <Name>MasterComponent</Name>
          <SubComponents>
                 <MyComponent>
                   <ComponentID>CMP_002</ComponentID>
                   <Name>Bar</Name>
                   <Subcomponents>
                      <MyComponent>
                         <ComponentID>CMP_001</ComponentID>
                         <Name>Foo</Name>
                      <MyComponent>
                    </Subcomponents>
                  </MyComponent>
                  <MyComponent>
                     <ComponentID>CMP_003</ComponentID>
                     <Name>Blergle</Name>
                  </MyComponent>  
         </SubComponents>
      </MyComponent>
   </Components>
 </Thing>
```

As you can see there's a lot of redundancy. `MasterComponent` contains the full definition of *all* other components (there's quite a few other fields, I omitted them for brevity). I'd like to see serialize it like this:

```
<Thing>
  <ID>TH_001<ID>
  <Name>My Test Thing</Name>
  <Components>
        <MyComponent>
            <ComponentID>CMP_001</ComponentID>
            <Name>Foo</Name>
        </MyComponent>        
        <MyComponent>
            <ComponentID>CMP_002</ComponentID>
            <Name>Bar</Name>
            <Subcomponents>
                <MyComponent ID="CMP_001" />
            </Subcomponents>
        </MyComponent>
        <MyComponent>
            <ComponentID>CMP_003</ComponentID>
            <Name>Blergle</Name>
        </MyComponent>   
        <MyComponent>
           <ID>CMP_004</ID>
           <Name>MasterComponent</Name>
          <SubComponents>
                 <MyComponent ID="CMP_002" />
                 <MyComponent ID="CMP_003" />
          </SubComponents>
      </MyComponent>
   </Components>
 </Thing>
```

In this situation, a component is only fully defined once, and then it's referenced by ID after that. I'm not quite sure how to best approach this, or if there's a better way.

Comment: How are you planning to use this serialized XML afterwards? I'm not quite sure why the redundancy would be a problem...

Comment: @Baldrick: I was planning to transform the XML to HTML and I looked at the first version of it and thought "Oh this is going to be messy, why can't I just reference the existing components by some kind of identifier?" ... I suppose I should actually *try* to perform a transformation on the first XML sample, but my gut reaction was "ugh!". I should probably try again in a few days when I'm not so tired.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [XML serialization attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). They provide a slew of options for controlling the output. For example, if you want to serialize class properties as attributes, you can just add a XmlAttribute:

```
[XmlAttribute(AttributeName="id")]
private String componentID;
```